# LazyLoadingEnabled false but still not loading

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I have the following in my EF code first data model:

```
public class B
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   ... some data ..
}

public class D: B
{
    public D() { RelatedData = new List<RelatedData>(); }
    public List<RelatedData> RelatedData { get; set; }
}

public class RelatedData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DId { get; set; }
    ... some data ...
}
```

In the database, I am going to lookup a record D which has 2 RelatedData records.

My access routine gets the data through the base class.

```
B Lookup(int desiredId)
{
    ...
    using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        B b = (from x in db.B
               where x.Id == desiredId
               select x).FirstOrDefault();

        // b is actually a type D; however, ReleatedData has no records.
        // If I serialize b and return it, ReleatedData is empty.

        // Running this silly code below when I am dealing with a type D
        // which really only hits the DB and throws away the data now forces
        // the related data in b to load.
        if ( b is  D)
        {
            var notUsed = (from r in db.RelatedData
                           where r.DId == desiredId
                           select r).ToList();

            // Serializing b now gives valid results.
        }
    }
}
```

}

Why do I have to go through the extra step of retrieving the related data?  Should the LazyLoadingEnabled = false force all of the related data to load during the first query?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be first use the `OfType` extension method to work only with the `D` entities and then use `Include` extension method to eager load `RelatedData` navigation property.

```
var d= db.B.OfType<D>().Include(d=>d.RelatedData).FirstOrDefault(d=>d.Id == desiredId);
```

Now about your question, you don't need to do an extra query to load the related entities. If you enable lazy loading again and declare `RelatedData` property as `virtual`, you will see EF is going to load that related entity when you consult that property after your first query. If you want to see the requirements you need to follow in your POCO entities, check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Update

Well, as I said in my comment, maybe you are missing something that don't let lazy loading works properly.

Another solution could be [load explicitly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit) that navigation property:

```
 D entity= b as D;
context.Entry(entity).Collection(p => p.RelatedData).Load();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have multiple classes that subclass B so restricting to only results of a certain type using OfType won't work.  Secondly, I have RelatedData as: 
public virtual List<RelatedData> RelatedData {get; set; }
In my attempted to make the code a generic as possible for publishing to this site, I accidentally deleted that.

Comment: That's odd, did you check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) with the requirements you need to follow.Entity Framework creates proxies for POCO entities if the classes meet those requirements. Maybe you are missing something. Anyways I'm going to share another solution with you.

Comment: I think you have hit upon the problem.  ProxyCreationEnabled is set to false by someone else.  I'm not sure why but when I set it to true, other things start breaking.  I probably need to do some follow-up investigation as to why this was choosen.  Thanks again for your help.